# Append material from blend file - path file to .blend

Tags: python, materials

I made some addon which one contain the blend file.

I would like to append some materials/data from this .blend into my addon.
everything was working fine when I was runing the script manually.

After I convert this script to addon.
My material isnt append.

I add .blend file to zipped folder with all my script.
After I install addon. I have .blend in  this folder

C:\Users\Kamil\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3

How to tell blender to use the same path for blend file, where my addon was installed by blender.
Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure that L0Lock is right - the reason is the wrong path. If you are running the script locally or via add-on - it is a total different path Blender uses. So i recommend using some print statements in your code so you can checkout which path your scipt uses in the add-on case.

Comment: Hello, @KamilD.. it does look to me as if this question has been answered elsewhere, so it's fair to call this a duplicate. If I'm wrong, please edit with a link to the non-duplicate, explaining the difference, and we can re-open for you.